# Magento 2 - Create or change customer to set customerID

Tags: magento2, programmatically

Is there a way to create a customer programmatically and set the customer ID?
Or is there a way to change it afterwards?

We are getting customer data from a central system in csv format and would like to create customer with the same ID like in the central system

Answer (score 2):

The customer id is an auto-incremented column in the database, so any solution I can think of would be a hack at best. I would recommend creating a new Customer attribute that contains the reference ID (something like `centralsystem_id`). You can specify the requirements around that attribute and how/when it is set as well.